# CASE When a different value is null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've looked at multiple examples, but I can't see why this SQL statement says "Incorrect syntax near IS and THEN"

I am trying to set the status_date column based on if the page has been changed.
So, if `@page_has_not_changed` is null then `status_date` should equal `status_date.

When `@page_has_not_changed` is `1` then `status_date` should equal `status_date` again.

When `@page_has_not_changed` is `0` then `status_date` should equal `GETDATE()`

Here is my query.

```
SET     status_ID = @status_id,
        page_has_not_changed = @page_has_not_changed,
        status_date = CASE @page_has_not_changed
                  --is and null below has syntax issue
                    WHEN IS NULL Then status_date
                    WHEN 1 Then status_date
                    ELSE GETDATE() END,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the alternate `case` syntax:

```
SET     status_ID = @status_id,
        page_has_not_changed = @page_has_not_changed,
        status_date = CASE
                  --is and null below has syntax issue
                    WHEN @page_has_not_changed IS NULL Then status_date
                    WHEN @page_has_not_changed = 1 Then status_date
                    ELSE GETDATE() END
```

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the *Simple CASE expression* (the one you were using), "*Allows only an equality check*". `IS NULL` is not an equality check.

Comment: I guess the follow up larger question is why does the other syntax work sometimes, but this one works other times.

Comment: @christopherclark Thanks for your comment. I read the documentation and figured out why the simple case statement did not work. I actually only used the `CASE WHEN <expr> THEN ...`, and wasn't really aware there was a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 2):

```
status_date = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@page_has_not_changed, 1) = 1 
                THEN status_date 
                ELSE GETDATE() 
              END
```

This does the same but with only 2 branches in your case. The `ISNULL` will cover the case where `@page_has_not_changed` is NULL and return a 1 instead, making your expression hit true for both NULL and 1 values.

Comment: If it's `0` . The page has changed, and I would need to update the status date

Comment: Altered. Just have your ISNULL return 1 in case of NULL & check for 1.

Answer (score 1):

Remove IS NULL to NULL, in your case you are already checking for value whereas in WHEN @page_has_not_changed IS NULL you are doing checks here

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET     status_ID = @status_id,
        page_has_not_changed = @page_has_not_changed,
        status_date = (CASE @page_has_not_changed
                  --is and null below has syntax issue
                    WHEN NULL Then status_date
                    WHEN 1 Then status_date
                    ELSE GETDATE() END),
                page_has_not_changed = @page_has_not_changed
```

However you should also add

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
```

**BUT**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

> In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Comment: @christopherclark I think this answers your question as to why your query didn't actually work

Comment: @christopherclark Weird. Can you guys look at [this code](http://pastebin.com/8vek900F)? For me it returns the wrong result in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @w0lf you need to do SET ANSI_NULLS OFF as it is NULL =  NULL

Comment: @brykneval OK, now I got it. But the assumption that this option is set should probably be specified in your answer.

Comment: @w0lf true, its not recommended, it was fix for what he was doing wrong will edit answer